# Neither tsc nor eslint show TypeScript errors in Node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to setup TypeScript in an existing Node project. I've already set it up in existing ReactJS project where it works flawlessly using ESLint and the Airbnb configuration. However, in this project, neither ESLint nor TSC itself (using `--noemit`) report errors despite the `strict` setting and deliberately including type errors in the source files.

Interestingly, when I delete the tsconfig.json file, ESLint does report errors. It says it can't resolve require() and I should install the type definitions for Node. Already did that, yet it's still reporting those errors. When I add my tsconfig.json, it displays none at all again.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2021",
      "strict": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "security"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base",
        "airbnb-typescript/base",
        "plugin:security/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2021,
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "ignorePatterns": ["test/**/*"],
    "rules": {
        "no-plusplus": "off",
        "no-restricted-syntax": "off",
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
        "max-len": ["error", 120, 2, {
            "ignoreUrls": true,
            "ignoreComments": false,
            "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true,
            "ignoreStrings": false,
            "ignoreTemplateLiterals": false,
            "classMethodsUseThis": false
        }]
    }
}
```

Does anyone see what's wrong here?

Comment: Does it work with `plugins: [ ... '@typescript-eslint']`?

Comment: This ts files are in the src directory, correct?

Comment: @JeffRSon Unfortunately not.

Comment: @cWerning Yes, they are in the src directory; relative to the tsconfig.json. Got a similar directory structure in the React project where it works.

Comment: do you have an example file where tsc doesn't report an error? complete minimal project would be helpful